# From stdClass to array then encode Json

Tags: php, json

I've try to convert an object of stdClass and encode it in a Json file but my Array is empty:

```
        createJson();
        $array = json_encode($jsonEncode);
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
        $fp = fopen('file.json', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $array);
        fclose($fp);
        unset($_POST);

function createJson(){
    $jsonEncode->Nome=$_POST["firstName"];
    $jsonEncode->Cognome=$_POST["lastName"];
    $jsonEncode->Indirizzo=$_POST["address"];
    $jsonEncode->Data_di_nascita="25/01/1977";
    $jsonEncode->Username=$_POST["userName"];
    $jsonEncode->Foto_profilo="percorso_foto";
    $jsonEncode->Skill = array(
        array("Falegnameria","Ottimo"),
        array("Inglese","Ottimo"),
        array("Relazioni col pubblico","Buono"),
        array("Saponeria","Discreto"),
        array("Caccia alla volpe","Eccellente")
    );
    $jsonEncode->Esperienze = array(
        array("Ottobre 2001","Gennaio 2016","Falegname","Cace srl"),
        array("Febbraio 2016","Gennaio 2017","Falegname","Cille snc")
    );
}
```

When I launch my Html page and submit my data I received this error:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in path_to_my_file on line 115("$jsonEncode->Nome=$_POST["firstName"];")
Warning: fopen(file.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in path_to_my_file on line 105

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in path_to_my_file on line 106

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in path_to_my_file on line 107

Where I wrong?

Comment: Hint is `variable scope`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_encode(createJson());
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
        $fp = fopen('file.json', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $array);
        fclose($fp);
        unset($_POST);

function createJson(){
    $jsonEncode['Nome'] = $_POST["firstName"];
    $jsonEncode['Cognome']= $_POST["lastName"];
    $jsonEncode['Indirizzo']=$_POST["address"];
    $jsonEncode['Data_di_nascita']="25/01/1977";
    $jsonEncode['Username']=$_POST["userName"];
    $jsonEncode['Foto_profilo']="percorso_foto";
    $jsonEncode['Skill'] = array(
        array("Falegnameria","Ottimo"),
        array("Inglese","Ottimo"),
        array("Relazioni col pubblico","Buono"),
        array("Saponeria","Discreto"),
        array("Caccia alla volpe","Eccellente")
    );
    $jsonEncode['Esperienze'] = array(
        array("Ottobre 2001","Gennaio 2016","Falegname","Cace srl"),
        array("Febbraio 2016","Gennaio 2017","Falegname","Cille snc")
    );

    return $jsonEncode; 
}
```